# In Geotools, why does reprojecting the origin of a GridGeometry2D results in off-the-grid coordinates?

Tags: geotools

I have a simple `GridGeometry2D` in Geotools 13.1 that is created like this:

```
GridEnvelope grid = new GridEnvelope2D(0, 0, 100, 100);
Envelope2D envelope = new Envelope2D(CRS.decode("EPSG:3857"), 10.0, 10.0, 1.0, 1.0);
GridGeometry2D geom = new GridGeometry2D(grid, envelope);
```

For a quick test, I'm trying to find the grid coordinates for point (10.0, 10.0):

```
DirectPosition out = geom.getCRSToGrid2D().transform(
                (DirectPosition) new DirectPosition2D(10.0, 10.0), 
                (DirectPosition) new DirectPosition2D());
```

I expected the result for the `x` field to be `0.5` (since the default pixel anchoring mode is center), but instead this happened:

`DirectPosition2D[-0.5000000000001137, 99.5]`

I understand that the `99.5` is probably because the `GridGeometry2D` considers that `y` coordinates increase towards the north, but the `GridEnvelope2D` `y`coordinates apparently increase towards the south (as it is common in image processing).

What I don't understand is why the `x` coordinate is negative if the minimal `x` for my grid is `0`. Why is this happening?